# foreign key linked field "Author" of a table "skills" is always empty in the database

Tags: python, django

I am building a web application where students can see the job posts posted by tutors. tutors can login into the site and post jobs. I created a "my post" page for tutors to see all their posts and Edit, Delete them. It seems that a foreign key field "author" comes empty in the database after posting a job which makes the post not to show up in my posts. Please help.

Here is my models.py for Skills:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    skill_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        choices=SKILL_CHOICES,
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=65)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    cost = models.IntegerField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=65)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.skill_type + " " + self.name)
```

Here is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('home', views.index, name='home'),
    path('signup', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('postskill', views.postskill, name='postskill'),
    path('profile', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('post/<int:id>', views.post, name='post'),
]
```

views.py for postskill and post(postskill is a modelform)

```
@login_required
def postskill(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.user.id)
        print(request.user.username)
        form = PostRecord(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            s = Skill(
                # author = request.user.id,
                teacher_name = request.user.username,
                skill_type = data.get('skill_type'),
                name = data.get('name'),
                duration = data.get('duration'),
                cost = data.get('cost'),
                location = data.get('location'),
            )
            s.save()

        allskills = Skill.objects.all().order_by('name')
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'skills': allskills})
    else:
        form = PostRecord()
        return render(request, 'postskill.html', {'form': form})

def post(request,id):
    logged_in_user_posts = Skill.objects.filter(author=id)
    return render(request, 'post.html', {'posts': logged_in_user_posts})
```

post.html template:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}

{% for post in posts %}

    Username: {{ post.author.username }}
    <ul>
    <li>Subject Type: {{post.skill_type}}</li>
    <li>Subject Name: {{post.name}}</li>
    <li>Duration: {{post.duration}} months</li>
    <li>Cost: Rs. {{post.cost}}</li>
    <li>Location: {{post.location}}</li>
    </ul>
    <br>

{% endfor %}


{% endblock %}
```

Here is an screenshot for postskill. When I post something. The post shows up in home page but not in the myposts page
[image]

Take a look at database. If i manually edit the author. the post shows up in Post page. [image]

Comment: You've commented the line ` # author = request.user.id` in your views.py, so the author isn't stored, right?

Comment: if i use that line. i would get the error : alueError at /postskill

Cannot assign "1": "Skill.author" must be a "User" instance.

Comment: Have you tried without the id? I mean `author = request.user`

Comment: Yes. It throws a CSRF missing error

Comment: You haven't posted the HTML template for your input form, but could it be that you did not add `{% csrf_token %}` to your form?

Answer (score 0):

Try uncommenting the line:

```
#author=request.user.id
```

And make it:

```
author=request.user
```

You said:”
Yes. It throws a CSRF missing error “

You have to login to request an user’s id is why.

Comment: Solved. But can you please elaborate why did it throw a CSRF error before?